# Pandas DataFrame grouping to generate numerical multi-index

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

I would like to apply a group by operation to a Pandas DataFrame without performing any aggregation. Instead, I just want the hierarchical structure to be reflected in the MultiIndex.

```
import pandas as pd

def multi_index_group_by(df, columns):
    # TODO: How to write this? (Hard-coded to give the desired result for the example.)
    if columns == ["b"]:
        df.index = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[0,1],[0,1,2]], labels=[[0,1,0,1,0],[0,0,1,1,2]])
        return df
    if columns == ["c"]:
        df.index = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[0,1],[0,1],[0,1]], labels=[[0,1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1,1],[0,0,1,0,0]])
        return df

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        "a": [0,1,2,3,4],
        "b": ["b0","b1","b0","b1","b0"],
        "c": ["c0","c0","c0","c1","c1"],
    })
    print(df.index.values) # [0,1,2,3,4]


    # Add level of grouping
    df = multi_index_group_by(df, ["b"])
    print(df.index.values) # [(0, 0) (1, 0) (0, 1) (1, 1) (0, 2)]

    # Examples
    print(df.loc[0]) # Group 0
    print(df.loc[1,1]) # Group 1, Item 1


    # Add level of grouping
    df = multi_index_group_by(df, ["c"])
    print(df.index.values) # [(0, 0, 0) (1, 0, 0) (0, 0, 1) (1, 1, 0) (0, 1, 0)]

    # Examples
    print(df.loc[0]) # Group 0
    print(df.loc[0,0]) # Group 0, Sub-Group 0
    print(df.loc[0,0,1]) # Group 0, Sub-Group 0, Item 1
```

What would be the best way to implement `multi_index_group_by`? The following almost works, but the resulting index isn't numerical:

```
index_columns = []
# Add level of grouping
index_columns += ["b"]
print(df.set_index(index_columns, drop=False))
# Add level of grouping
index_columns += ["c"]
print(df.set_index(index_columns, drop=False))
```

*Edit:* To clarify, in the example, the final indexing should be equivalent to:

```
[
    [ #b0
        [ #c0
            {"a": 0, "b": "b0", "c": "c0"},
            {"a": 2, "b": "b0", "c": "c0"},
        ],
        [ #c1
            {"a": 4, "b": "b0", "c": "c1"},
        ]
    ],
    [ #b1
        [ #c0
            {"a": 1, "b": "b1", "c": "c0"},
        ],
        [ #c1
            {"a": 3, "b": "b1", "c": "c1"},
        ]
    ]
]
```

*Edit:* Here is the best I've got so far:

```
def autoincrement(value=0):
    def _autoincrement(*args, **kwargs):
        nonlocal value
        result = value
        value += 1
        return result
    return _autoincrement

def swap_levels(df, i, j):
    order = list(range(len(df.index.levels)))
    order[i], order[j] = order[j], order[i]
    return df.reorder_levels(order)

def multi_index_group_by(df, columns):
    new_index = df.groupby(columns)[columns[0]].aggregate(autoincrement())

    result = df.join(new_index.rename("_new_index"), on=columns)
    result.set_index('_new_index', append=True, drop=True, inplace=True)
    result.index.name = None
    result = swap_levels(result, -2, -1)
    return result
```

It gives the correct result, except for the last level, which is unchanged. Still feels like there is quite a bit of room for improvement.

Comment: What is the meaning of your hardcoded MultiIndex?

Comment: @desiato It is a steadily increasing nd index (see the examples). For example (0,1,2,...) means: Group 0, Sub-Group 1, Sub-Sub-Group 2 etc.

Comment: Essentially, I want to be able to address rows in the same way you would index into a nested list.

Comment: is your hardcoded MultiIndex for column `b` correct? Which subgroup represents the `2` in the last tuple?

Comment: @desiato I believe it is correct. In the example, there are only two levels of nesting. The last index selects the item from the group. I have added a list structure that would be equivalent to the indexing I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are willing to use the [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) package you could use the [LabelEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()

def multi_index_group_by(df, columns):
    df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples( zip( *[ le.fit_transform( df[col] ) for  col in columns ] ) )
    return df
```

It encodes labels of each column with value between 0 and n_classes-1

calling

```
multi_index_group_by( ['b','c'] )
```

gives you

```
     a   b   c
0 0  0  b0  c0
1 0  1  b1  c0
0 0  2  b0  c0
1 1  3  b1  c1
0 1  4  b0  c1
```

Comment: Wow, yeah, that seems pretty close to what I ended up with (see the latest edit to my question). Not sure if it is worth the dependency on sklearn, but interesting suggestion, thanks!

Comment: I will accept this answer, since it mostly does what I want. If anyone needs an alternative without dependency on sklearn, see the edits to my question.

Answer (score 1):

This code does what you want:

```
index_columns = []
replace_values = {}

index_columns += ["b"]
replace_values.update({'b0':0, 'b1':1})

df[['idx_{}'.format(i) for i in index_columns]] = df[index_columns].replace(replace_values)
print(df.set_index(['idx_{}'.format(i) for i in index_columns], drop=True))

index_columns += ["c"]
replace_values.update({'c0':0, 'c1':1})

df[['idx_{}'.format(i) for i in index_columns]] = df[index_columns].replace(replace_values)
print(df.set_index(['idx_{}'.format(i) for i in index_columns], drop=True))

# If you want the 3rd ('c') level MultiIndex:
df['d'] = [0,0,1,0,0]
print(df.set_index(['idx_{}'.format(i) for i in index_columns] + ['d'], drop=True))
```

Comment: Yes, I was toying around with something similar, but it would be nice if I didn't have to keep track of the indices manually. Thanks for the suggestion though, if nothing better comes up, I will accept it.